# How can I create a addtional column and use partition by clause in inferschma synatx

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am reading data from s3 to create an external table in snowflake using inferschmea. I am getting all columns from the expression column but want to additional columns date to use it in the partition by. How can I achieve this using inferschmea?

```
create or replace external table people_test1
  using template (
    select expression,filenames, substr(filenames,24,10) DATE_PART
 
      from table(
        infer_schema(
          location=>'@ITCHBOD.COMPANY_STAGE/cre/invets/',
          file_format=>'CRUPARQUET',
          partition by (DATE_PART)
        )
      ) 
  )
```

Comment: ```partition by``` is used with external table and infer_schema as I understand is to be used with normal table (no external clause)

Comment: @pankaj how can i inferschmea to create a external table?

Comment: There is no ```template``` clause in ```create external table``` [syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#syntax)

Comment: Then how can i use inferschme with create external table??

Comment: I dont think there is any direct way, unless you were to write a program to get values from ```infer_schema``` and store those values as string(s) to be used later in ```create external table``` statement.

Comment: @Pankaj You **can** use `template` with `create external table`: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table#external-table-created-with-detected-column-definitions